# Concatenate string in MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, mips

Unable to concatenate strings using the library string.h in C language I wonder how do I do the same code in mips, asking the user to enter two words and then inform the concatenation of words.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int main ()
{
 char string1 [100], string2 [100];

 printf ("\n");
 printf ("Joining two strings \n");
 printf ("------------------- \n");
 printf ("\n");
 printf ("string1");
 scanf ("%s", &string1);
 printf ("\n");
 printf ("string2");
 scanf ("%s", &string2);
 printf ("\n");
 printf ("Joining string1 string2: %s \n \n", strcat (string1, string2));
 return (0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the scanf statements.
The name of the char array points to the start of the array - hence no need for the `&` operators in scanf statements.

```
 printf ("string1");
 scanf ("%s", string1);
 printf ("\n");
 printf ("string2");
 scanf ("%s", string2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. I wonder how it would be this code in mips assembly language?